# Subprocess.Popen to open an .exe terminal program and input to the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to open a .csv file using a .exe file. Both the file and program are contained in the same folder. When manually opening the folder I drag the csv file ontop of the exe, it then opens and I press any key to commence the program.

When using the shell I can do what I want using this script

```
E:
cd ISAAC\SWEM\multiprocess\2000
SWEM_1_2000_multiprocess.exe "seedMIXsim.csv"
<wait for program to initialize>
<press any key>
```

So far in python3 I have tried several variations of subprocess, the latest using Popen with an input argument of ="h" as a random key should start the program.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
        ['E://ISAAC//SWEM//multiprocess//2010//SWEM_1_2010_multiprocess.exe', '"E://ISAAC//SWEM//multiprocess//2010//seedMIXsim.csv"'], input="h")
```

However, when I input any arguments such as stdout or input, the python program will almost immediately finish without doing anything.
Ideally, I would like to open a visible cmd window while running the program as the exe runs in the terminal and shows a progress bar.

Comment: Try running your line of code in an interactive Python shell to see if it raises an exception and to experiment with arguments. Also don't those paths need `'\\'` instead of `//`? Do read the docs on `subprocess` for info on ensuring the program gets console input and output and on waiting for the program to finish.

Comment: After creating a Popen instance, you need to call `proc.wait()` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by replacing // with \ and using proc.communicate to wait until the process finishes. This comes down to the specific design of the C program, which exits with "press any key".

```
def openFile(swemPath):
    simFile =(swemPath +'seedMIXsim.csv').replace('//', '\\')
    swemFile = f"E:\ISAAC\preSWEMgen\SWEMfiles\SWEM{cfg.hoursPerSimulation}hour.exe"
    proc = subprocess.Popen([swemFile, simFile], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    wait = proc.communicate(input=b" ")
```